# Разница между UML диаграммами

Tags: ооп, uml

Не могу понять, диаграмма классов и диаграмма Буча - это одно и то же или между ними есть какие-то различия. Если да, то какие?

Answer (score 1):

Метод Буча - это предтеча RUP (Rational Unified Process), читай UML.

Т.е. фактически, если рассматривать UML 1.x, то можно считать, что это одно и то-же.

Однако UML развивается, уточняется и дополняется семантика языка. Сейчас актуальна версия 2.5.

Другими словами, диаграмму Буча можно рассматривать как диаграмму UML, но вот обратное не факт, что будет верно.